# Not getting updated values after call to AngularJS $save

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, angular-resource

Folks,
  I am using AngularJS and angular-resource to perform a pretty simple REST API call. Here is my JavaScript code for a page that lists (and creates) messages:

```js
(function() {
'use strict';
var messagesApp = angular.module('messagesApp', ['ngResource']);

messagesApp.factory('Message', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/messages/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        query: {method:'GET', isArray:true} });
});

messagesApp.controller('MessagesCtrl',
  function($scope, Message) {
    $scope.messages = Message.query();

    $scope.addMessage = function() {
        $.Dialog({
            'title': 'Add new Message',
            'content': '<p>Enter the <strong>unique</strong> name of the new message.</p><input type="text" id="newMessageName"/><p>Enter the <strong>unique</strong> ID for this message.</p><input type="text" id="newID"/>',
            'draggable': false,
            'overlay': true,
            'closeButton': true,
            'buttonsAlign': 'right',
            'buttons': {
                'save': {
                    'action' : function() {
                        var newMessage = new Message();
                        newMessage.name = $('#newMessageName').val()
                        newMessage.altid= parseInt($('#newID').val())
                        newMessage.longDescription = "This is a new message";
                        newMessage.$save();
                        console.log(newMessage.id)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
  }
);
})();
```

What happens is the console log message prints out 'undefined'. When I look at the network log, I see that my REST API is indeed returning the newly created object when it comes back.. Should I not be using Ok as a result type and instead use something else? Is there an HTTP header I'm missing .. or am I using the $save thing wrong??

The $.Dialog() method comes from another JavaScript library I'm using (metroui.og.ua) and I don't know if that's interfering with this or not..

Comment: I don't know if it's clear from the original post, but the actual network call to save my resource IS made, and the body of the response from the POST is actually the JSON containing the newly created object, with the id property set.

Comment: Your use case might be super simple, and this may be overkill, but you might consider replacing that $.Dialog call within your controller. Take a look at AngularJS Bootstrap - they have a Dialog directive that works really well. It'd allow you to pull that HTML out of your controller, and simplify things a bit. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`newMessage.$save()` is asynchronous, so if you want to get a hold of the response data you should do it in the success callback function:

```js
newMessage.$save(function(msg, headers){
  console.log(newMessage.id); // note, at this point msg === newMessage
});
```

See [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: This did the trick. For some reason the samples I saw in the documentation for $resource didn't stick out as async and I missed that.

Comment: Actually, the ngResource documentation you link to doesn't exist. It's just a couple of comments. I found it very difficult to find any good examples of $resource in action.

Comment: I've fixed the link, there are some examples there