# AngularJS: Retrieve newly created Record Id in CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

To create a new record added from a form in AngularJS, I have:

```
task = Task.save($scope.newTask)
```

But I need to also retrieve the new id that was created upon save. The answer found here: [Not getting updated values after call to AngularJS $save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866265/not-getting-updated-values-after-call-to-angularjs-save) seems to address what I need, but when I convert to CoffeeScript:

```
task = $scope.newTask
task.$save (msg, headers) ->
  console.log task.id
```

It does not work. I am using Ruby on Rails. Any help is appreciated.

## **Edit:**

I am getting the error on the code above: "Object # has no method 'save'"

Here is a bigger picture of my code:

```
app = angular.module("appName", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Task", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/projects/:project_id/tasks/:id", {project_id: "@project_id", id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}, destroy: { method: 'DELETE' }})
]

@TaskCtrl = ["$scope", "Task", ($scope, Task) ->
  $scope.tasks = Task.query()

  $scope.saveTask = ->
      task = $scope.newTask
      task.$save (msg, headers) ->
        console.log task.id
      $scope.tasks.push(task)
      $scope.newTask = {}
]
```

Comment: your coffeescript is correct, something else must be wrong... you are using this in success callback?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have edited my question for more detail.

Comment: `$scope.newTask` is not a Task resource, as it has no method `$save` (I assume the error message was "Object # has no method '$save'", because I see no method call to a function named `save` in your code). Where is `$scope.newTask` created?

Comment: I just have a form with ng-submit="saveTask()" and the various fields have 'ng-model="newTask.name"' etc. I am able to call $update no problem ... do I just need to add 'save' in my factory definition?

Comment: But where is `$scope.newTask` created? Somewhere you should have `$scope.newTask = new Task();`

Comment: hmmm. Perhaps this is the problem. All I have previously was task = Task.save($scope.newTask) was saving the data ... but I was not getting the actual saved object passed back from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save `newTask` as it was an instance of the `Task` resource, but it is not, you are creating it as an empty object (`$scope.newTask = {}`).

You should create it as `$scope.newTask = new Task()`

Or save is as you seem to suggest in the first line of code: `Task.save($scope.newTask)`.

The result of the `Task.save()` call will depend on what the server returns, it's JSON data, if you return the new ID in the JSON response of the POST request, then you'll get it in your data, if you just return an empty "created" response, with a `Location` header, you shuld subsequently retrieve the data. If you return nothing at all, that's the point in which you touch ruby, and return something useful from the server.